# Powershell: Add path, filename, filesize and filedate when converting xml to csv

Tags: xml, powershell, csv, prepend, fileinfo

I'm new to scripting; trying to create a powershell script that will read XMLs and create a CSV based on their content.

The directory structure is as follows:
c:\path\to\files

Inside there are 2 folders:
FolderA
FolderB
Inside each of the above there are several subfolders, each with one or more XML files.
Each XML file in turn can have 1 or more "records".

I have the following so far:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\path\to\files\*.xml' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  [xml]$xml = Get-Content $_.FullName
  $xml.SelectNodes('//File') |
    Select-Object
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\files\processed.csv' -NoType -Delimiter ';'
```

This works and creates a CSV file with the contents of all XML files.
What I'd like to do now is have the script above prepend the following information for each file:
path (ie. c:\path\to\files\FolderA\Subfolder1)
file name (ie. File1.xml)
file size (ie. 64 bytes)
file date (ie. Created on 1/1/2018)

These should be the first data in the csv, followed by the XML data; something like:

```
"path";"filename";"filesize";"filedate";"xmlroot";"xmlchild";"xmlsubchild"
```

As stated before, the xmlroot,xmlchild,xmlsubchild I already have with my current script, I just need the script to prepend the file information.
If this is not possible with the current script, I'll gladly accept other suggestions :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a set of calculated properties when grabbing the nodes with `Select-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\path\to\files\*.xml' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  $file = $_
  [xml]$xml = Get-Content $file.FullName
  $xml.SelectNodes('//File') |
    Select-Object @{Name='path';Expression={$file.FullName}},@{Name='filename';Expression={$file.Name}},@{Name='filesize';Expression={$file.Length}},@{Name='filedate';Expression={$_.CreationTime}},*
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\files\processed.csv' -NoType -Delimiter ';'
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your proposed script and it does prepend the information I need; however it brings another problem: after the prepend data it adds the XML data which is fine, but then goes on adding other data I don't know where it gets from and that I have no need for such as:  
Name LocalName NamespaceURI Prefix NodeType ParentNode OwnerDocument IsEmpty Attributes HasAttributes SchemaInfo InnerXml InnerText NextSibling PreviousSibling Value ChildNodes FirstChild LastChild HasChildNodes IsReadOnly OuterXml BaseURI PreviousText  
Any idea what's causing this and how to avoid it?

Comment: After a long day of trial and error, I was able to fix the issue:  
I needed to add @{Name='Name';Expression={$_.XMLValueName}}  
for each value I wanted returned. Now the script is giving me the exact data I wanted.